# tmux attach and current working directory

Tags: tmux

I have as on single command "new" in my $HOME/.tmux.conf so I can call tmux attach as a command automatically using ssh. Recently (I believe since version 2.7) I am seeing a strange effect that if I use "tmux attach" and I do not have a session running a new session is started as expected (as I have the new command in my .tmux.conf) but the current working directory is "." if I use echo $PWD. If I use tmux without arguments to create a new session anyways I get a normal $PWD, in my case it is $HOME as I always call tmux right after logging in.

This wreaks havoc with a few shell scripts, for example the mvim script is not able to open any files in macvim any longer. If I use "cd $HOME" after using tmux attach for the first time when it created a new default session it works OK. Does anybody have any clue on how to fix that without issuing "cd $HOME"?

Answer (score 0):

I just found that tmux version 2.8 fixes the problem.